# Java check String and match

Tags: java, string

I am trying to do a math operation and match a letter of a string:

I got this table:

```
static final char[] LETTERS = {'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D', 'X','B', 'N',  'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'K', 'E'};
```

[image: table]

And I am getting inputs from keyboard of ID's that are in 012345678X (8 digits + 1 char)

I am trying to make it check for 8digits+1char and got it done like this:

```
public void check() {
 if(input.matches("[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]{1}")){
status = true;}
```

My problem is that now I need to check the last entered letter matches the table by calculating the numbers of the input % 23.
Example of valid inputs:

- 00000102X since 102 % 23 = 10 and X is 10th letter in my char list;
- 24659213Q since 24659213 % 23 = 16 and Q is 16th letter in char list.

Now what I did try is this:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
if(input.matches("[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]{1}"))
    {
      switch(num){
        case 0: if(num%23==0){
            if(input.charAt(8)==LETTERS[0]){
                status = true;
                break;
            }}
....
        case 10: if(num%23==10){
            if(input.indexOf(8)==LETTERS[10]){
                status = true;
            }}

        default: status = false;
    }
```

But with no results, any idea where am I going wrong? It's not that I get a compilation or code error, just that every 8digit+1letter input I get it gets accepted. Thank you in advance!

***EDIT (PASTED CODE)***

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Testing {

    static final char[] LETRAS = {'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D', 'X'
                                 ,'B', 'N',  'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C'
                                 , 'K', 'E'};
    String input;
    public boolean status = false;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 //Método problema general
public static void main (String[] args) {
Testing programa = new Testing();
programa.inicio();
}

public void inicio() {
    Intro();
    while (!status){
    datosUsuario();
    comprobacion();
    resultado();
}
}

//Explicar programa
public void Intro() {
    System.out.println("¡Hola!\nEste programa pide y comprueba DNI's."
            + "A continuación va a pedir un DNI de forma 8 dígitos y una letra,"
            + "y va a comprobar si es válido.\n"
            + "Ejemplo DNI válido: 24659213Q\n\n");
}

//Métodos primer nivel de decomposición
//Pedir DNI por teclado
public void datosUsuario() {
    System.out.print("Escribe DNI: ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
}


//Comprobación DNI
public boolean comprobacion() {
    System.out.println("Comprobamos DNI...");
    char letra = input.charAt(8);
    if(input.matches("[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke]{1}"))
    {
        int numeros = Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
        if(LETRAS[numeros%LETRAS.length] == input.charAt(8)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//Mostrar resultado
public void resultado() {
    if(status&&comprobacion()){
        System.out.println("DNI válido!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do. Post an [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see many problems in your code , first I am not sure why is the switch for?
you can simply do it like this

```
    public static boolean isValid(String str) {

    if(str.matches("[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]{1}")) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
        if(LETTERS[num%LETTERS.length] == str.charAt(8) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to translate from spanish to make it understadable, sort of, and seems I failed. But you got it right and the code you gave seems to work but I can't get the program to show an OK or NOT OK reply now. Can I paste all the code here? even if it's in spanish?

Comment: You can simple call the method i wrote "isValid" and check if it returns true then print ok , if it returns false print Not Ok

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't parse the `String` before matching the regex. If the pattern does not match the `String` `input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")` could return the empty `String`; `Integer.parseInt` throws an exception in this case.
2. If the regex matches, you know which part of the `String` contains the number. Using `substring` is more efficient than using `replaceAll` in this case.
3. Just compare the char you get from the from the input with the char in the array. Don't use a `switch`.
4. If you compare the last letter with the element from the array, you do not need such a complicated character group. Just allow any character as the last one and leave the rest to the comparison with the array element.

```
static final char[] LETTERS = {'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D', 'X','B', 'N',  'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'K', 'E'};

public static boolean checkInput(String input) {
    return input.matches("[0-9]{8}.")
               && LETTERS[Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 8)) % LETTERS.length] == input.charAt(8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegexTester2 {

    static final char[] LETTERS = {'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D', 'X','B', 'N',  'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'K', 'E'};

    public static boolean isMatch(String input) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([0-9]{8})([TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE])$");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        if (m.matches()) {
            String strNum = m.group(1);
            String lastChar = m.group(2);
            int num = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
            int idx = num % 23;
            return LETTERS[idx] == lastChar.charAt(0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputs = {
                "00000102X",
                "24659213Q",
                "12345679Z"
        };

        for (String s : inputs) {
            System.out.println("match? " + s + " " + isMatch(s));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That works very well but I am getting inputs from keyboard by user. Updated my question with the entire code. Sorry if spanish makes it hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem about in your value " num ". You check if ( num % 23 == 10 ) but what is your num ? You need value for " num " you need the get from user or you can give this value yourself. You need this i think good luck.

Comment: Hi. num was the extracted int from the String. And I get inputs from scanner by user. Updated the post by adding all the code. Hope now makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]{1}");
final Matcher finder = pat.matcher(input);
final ArrayList<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();

while(finder.find()){
    char vchar;
    MatchResult mr = finder.toMatchResult();

    try {
        int vnum = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(mr.start(), mr.end() - 1));
        vchar = LETTERS[vnum % 23];
    } catch(Exception e){
        continue;
    }

    if(vchar == input.charAt(mr.end() - 1)){
        matchList.add(input.substring(mr.start(), mr.end()));
    }
}
```

The input is one string: `"00000102X00000102X"` would match twice. You could tweak the code to accept an array of input strings.